# TODO manager with hierarchical TODOs?

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, reminders, caldav

I use KDE4 on my Linux machines, one of the tools I use a lot is [KOrganizer](http://userbase.kde.org/KOrganizer). I love its TODO list which supports hierarchical (nested) tasks.

Could someone recommend a similar application for Mac? If it could synchronize with CalDAV server, that would be great. So far I failed to find any such tool.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You might get better results if you don't assume that everybody here knows KOrganizer. Can you extend the question to describe the functionality you are looking for in more details (including examples maybe) and also mention the tools you have looked at already and why they do not meet your requirements?

Comment: I named my requirements - hierarchical TODO, and preferably CalDAV support (directly, or via Mac OS calendars - it's more about vCalendar support). Perhaps I should be more explicit, indeed. Thx!

Comment: [TaskPaper](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/taskpaper) supports nested tasks, but I don't know if it can be used with CalDAV.

Answer (score 2):

This might be more than what you're looking for, but [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus) is the best solution that I'm aware of that meets your stated requirements.

It does do nested tasks.  If you're a fan of Getting Things Done, OmniFocus will feel pretty familiar to the workflow described therein.  If you're not into GTD, OF still works, although the terminology might not feel quite so obvious.

It supports WebDAV, not CalDAV.  If you're running your own CalDAV server, you might be fine here.  If sync (not necessarily CalDAV sync) is your real goal, the Omni Group has an Omni Sync Server that's available to all of its customers, and it works well.

There are also OmniFocus apps for iPhone and iPad, which have generally good reviews.

Comment: The downside of OmniFocus is that it is pretty expensive in contrast to iCal, Reminders and Wunderlist, which are for free.

Comment: I concur with that downside, but it has the upside of meeting the OP's stated requirements.  "Free" or "cheap" was not a stated requirement.  If I got downvoted because my solution met the stated requirements but is expensive, that seems rather unfair. :/

Comment: Indeed, OmniFocus is way too expensive for its value, but it's not the reason to downvote! Let me upvote then :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to keep both things separated: TODO-List manager and calendar app.

I would recommend the in-built iCal as calendar app on your Mac. Here, you can use a service like Google Calendar for syncing with another calendar app on your Linux machine.

If you want a really good TODO list manager, which is also available for different mobile platforms, I would recommend WUnderlist 2, it also has a beautiful web interface that you can use from your browser, so there is no need to install it: http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist

Comment: I already use iCal, and I use my own server for synchronization (open-source SOGo project) - works pretty well. I'm really only concerned with managing/synchronizing TODOs.

Comment: Please note that vCalendar standard supports TODOs - VTODO objects. It's supported by many tools, but unfortunately KOrganizer is the only one I know which supports nested TODOs.

Comment: Is it necessary to have your TODOs in a calendar app? I really recommend to use a specialized app for that.

Comment: Well, basically there is the `Reminders` application (introduced in 10.8) which uses CalDAV to represent and sync its reminders. It just misses the hierarchical stuff. I imagine that is the sort of SW that @CodePainters wants.

Comment: @Percival Ulysses - exactly, that's it! I want it to use CalDAV so it synchronizes over my existing setup, and in fact Reminders work well - if only it wasn't a flat list :)

Comment: I was also thinking about Reminders first, but it only has 1 level depth of hierarchy. You can basically create multiple lists with items, but no sub lists.

Comment: Multiple lists is what I do now. I'm afraid I have to start developing a custom tool in my spare time...